# Can I make GCS bucket only available to specific people (or with password)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I would like to share a web map created using the qgis2web plugin to a client, but I do not want to make the data public. Are there any way to share with someone in particular? I can't make sense of the information provided by the Google Cloud Storage platform...

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.  You can indeed grant access permissions to 3rd parties.  Here is a great article titled [Sharing buckets and files](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6280971). In order to share the data with a named individual, Google Cloud Storage has to know the identity of that individual.  This means that the user has to be part of your G Suite domain, part of your Cloud Identity configuration or linked with a Google Account email.

Answer (score 0):

From Google Documentation:

> *You can control who has access to your Cloud Storage buckets and objects as well as what level of access they have.*

[This link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/) contains information about Access control options for Google Cloud Storage.

In order to give access to certain *Entitys* in your GCS Bucket, a user can use the Cloud IAM permissions.

[Here you will find detailed instructions on how to do that.](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions#bucket-iam)

**Please note that:**

> You should set the minimum permission possible that gives the member
>   the required access. For example, if the team member only needs to
>   read objects stored in a bucket, select the Storage Object Viewer
>   role. Similarly, if the team member needs full control of objects in
>   the bucket (but not control of the bucket itself), select Storage
>   Object Admin.

[Here you will find the Cloud IAM roles for Cloud Storage with a short description of their use.](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles)

Please let me know if you need further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can grant any Google account with the role `storage.objectViewer`. There is a potential issue here: grant a **`Google account`**.

Your customer can create one [here](https://accounts.google.com) if it hasn't one

- Go to create account.
- If your customer want an address in gmail.com, it can continue.
- If not, it can click on `Use my current email address instead`. By the way, he can use any address email, and add a password on it to be authenticated by Google.

*This last part is something like your proposal to "set a password".*

Then go to your bucket permission, or even on your object permission, and grant the role to the customer email address.

*Note: If your organization has activated the Domain Restriction Sharing policy, this solution is not possible, except if the email address domain of your customer is whitelisted by the policy or if your project is whitelisted.*